# How to delete a file in NX generator

Tags: javascript, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-devkit

According to https://nx.dev/recipes/generators/creating-files

> Generators provide an API for managing files within your workspace. You can use generators to do things such as create, update, move, **and delete files**.

it's possible to delete files in an NX generator.

I have the following code that generates a node application but I want to delete some of the generated files.

```
import { readProjectConfiguration, Tree } from '@nrwl/devkit';
import { applicationGenerator } from '@nrwl/node'

export interface Schema {
  name: string
}

export default async function (tree: Tree, schema: Schema) {

  // create node application with name `schema.name`
  await applicationGenerator(tree, {
    name: schema.name
  })

  const projectRoot = readProjectConfiguration(tree, schema.name).sourceRoot
  if (!projectRoot) throw new Error(`${schema.name} is not a project found in project configuration`)

  // here I want to delete generated files:
  // apps/myapp/src/app/.gitkeep
  // apps/myapp/src/assets/.gitkeep
  // apps/myapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts
  // apps/myapp/src/environments/environment.ts
}
```

Output

```
CREATE apps/myapp/src/app/.gitkeep
CREATE apps/myapp/src/assets/.gitkeep
CREATE apps/myapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts
CREATE apps/myapp/src/environments/environment.ts
CREATE apps/myapp/src/main.ts
CREATE apps/myapp/tsconfig.app.json
CREATE apps/myapp/tsconfig.json
CREATE apps/myapp/project.json
CREATE apps/myapp/.eslintrc.json
CREATE apps/myapp/jest.config.ts
CREATE apps/myapp/tsconfig.spec.json
```

What API is used for deleting files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out to be very simple.

`tree.delete(filePath)`

In my case,

```
  ...
  // Delete generated files:
  // apps/myapp/src/app/.gitkeep
  // apps/myapp/src/assets/.gitkeep
  // apps/myapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts
  // apps/myapp/src/environments/environment.ts

  tree.delete(joinPathFragments(projectRoot, 'src/app'))
  tree.delete(joinPathFragments(projectRoot, 'src/assets'))
  tree.delete(joinPathFragments(projectRoot, 'src/environments'))
```